# Call an executable

Tags: external-calls

I have one data file, one executable file and one *.txt with the results from running the executable, all within the same folder.

The folder has the path

**C : \ Users \ Dimitris \ Desktop \C32EXE**

From a Mathematica notebook, I want to be able to open the data file which is called **composites.dat**.

Once making any modifications to the data file and save it, I want the same mathematica notebook to be able to run the executable file which is called 
**composites.exe**.

The executable file produces a *.txt file with the name **L.txt**.
I want the notebook to call this file.

Currently, I can do only the third step by executing

```
Import["C : \\ Users \\ Dimitris \\ Desktop \\C32EXE\\L.txt","Table"];
```

but for the others I need manual manipulations.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Run["start notepad C:\\Users\\Dimitris\\Desktop\\C32EXE\\composites.dat"];
```

Finish editing. Then:

```
Run["C:\\Users\\Dimitris\\Desktop\\C32EXE\\composites.exe"];
```